# onmouseover check a input radio button javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, radio-button

Instead of clicking on a radio button, how can we create a `onmouseover` event and javascript to make the radio button `checked` when simply hovering onto it? Please no jQuery.

```html
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" onmouseover="checkButton()" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" onmouseover="checkButton()">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" onmouseover="checkButton()">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" onmouseover="checkButton()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have the `checkButton` function pass in the element as the parameter then set the `element.checked` to true. For example:

```js
function checkButton(element){
  element.checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" onmouseover="checkButton(this)" checked="check">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" onmouseover="checkButton(this)">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" onmouseover="checkButton(this)">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" onmouseover="checkButton(this)">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would even add to what jakekimds did and avoid putting your javascript inline on your inputs to separate presentation and functionality. So you would get

HTML

```
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example1">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example2">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example3">
<input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example4">
```

JS

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('tryout');
[].forEach.call(inputs, function(el){
    el.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
        this.checked = true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the radio buttons in a container, you can then use document.getElementById to attach an event handler.  That way, if your JavaScript changes, your HTML doesn't.

```
<span id="radio-buttons">
    <input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example" checked="check">
    <input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example">
    <input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example">
    <input type="radio" class="tryout" name="example">
</span>
<script>
document.getElementById("radio-buttons").onmouseover = function (e) {
    e.target.checked = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: For IE compatibility, see this site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target